# UIView Shadow Outside Parent View

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

My problem is pretty straight forward. I am using a custom cell in a `UITableView`. The cell is transparent and inside it's `contentView` has another `UIView` that is white, has rounded corners and a shadow at the bottom.

The thing is that the child view's shadow isn't fully shown. I don't want to further extend the `contentView` so that there is room for it.

So my question is the following: Can I somehow make the shadow show visible outside of the cell's `contentView`? Or is there something else that I could do?

EDIT: Here's my code (it's inside a subclass of UITableViewCell)

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Rectangle
    let rectangle = CGRectMake(10, 10, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width-20 , 100)
    let rectView = UIView(frame: rectangle)

    // Rectangle Customization
    rectView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    rectView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    rectView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    rectView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    rectView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    rectView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)

    contentView.addSubview(rectView)
}
```

Comment: you can directly add UIView to cell. and not to the cell.contentView

Just do cell.addSubView(), instead of cell.contentView.addSubView()

Comment: It doesn't work. The code is inside a custom cell class. How do I access the cell there? Autocomplete won't show anything named "cell"

Comment: `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCustomCellClass`
And then, `cell.imageView.image = ...`

Comment: There's no `indexPath` nor `tableView`..

Comment: Here, I have answered. Good that you updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I changed the strategy a bit. The `cells` were **110pt** tall and the `rectangle` is **100pt** tall. The rectangle was at Y=10 inside the `cell`.

So it was touching the bottom and wasn't enough room for the shadow.

Then I just set Y=0 so there were 10pts available at the bottom for the shadow. Then for the 1st cell to have some space at the top(the 10pts that the other cells have), I just added a blank `label` at the top of the `UITableView` that was 10pt tall.

Not sure if best solution, but it works and I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
contentView.addSubview(rectView)
```

to

```
  addSubview(rectView)
```

Comment: Same problem. It seems that it just automatically adds it to the `contentView`. The shadow is still not fully visible.

Comment: I only changed that line. I also tried moving it ahead of the shadow code but same result.

Comment: can you see any shadow at all?

Comment: Yes. The shadow is there, but as I said, I guess XCode interprets `addSubview` just like `contentView.addSubview` in this case. It adds the `rectView` to the `contentView`.

Comment: Alternatively, to get the result I want, I could just move the rect 10pt up (so Y is 0), but I would have to move all of them 10pt down, because the first cell won't have a 10pt space on top. How can I do that?